# Why would my Edit Form be view-able but not my New form of the same controller?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror, nested-resources

If I click on my edit link the link works and takes me to the edit form for the particular gallery I'd like to edit. If I click on the link to the new for the same controller I get the following error:

```
    NoMethodError at /users/2/galleries/new
undefined method `galleries_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f4714fbac68>:0x000000060f32e0>
Did you mean?  gallery_path
```

I've done extensive searching for the solution to this, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. This was working fine until I updated the routes to have galleries a nested resource to the user. I was in the process of updating/correcting my links and forms when I couldn't figure out how to get past this issue.

Below are my routes, the galleries/_form, galleries/edit, galleries/_new, parts of the gallery controller.

```
routes.rb    
resources :users, shallow: true do
        resources :galleries
        resources :images
        resources :albums
    end

galleries.html.erb
<h1>New Gallery</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Dashboard', user_path(current_user) %>

galleries/edit.html.erb
<h1>Update Gallery</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Dashboard', user_path(current_user) %>

galleries_controller.rb
def new
        @gallery = current_user.galleries.new
    end

    def create
        @gallery = current_user.galleries.build(gallery_params)
        respond_to do |format|
                if @gallery.save
                    format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
                    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @gallery }
                else
                    format.html { render :new }
                    format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                end
            end
    end

    def show
    end

    def update
        if @gallery.update_attributes(gallery_params)
            flash[:success] = "Gallery Updated"
            redirect_to @gallery
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
private

    def set_gallery
        @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    end

    def gallery_params
        params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, images_files: [])
    end
```

If you need more from me let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using 1 form for edit and new. I made two separate forms, violating DRY principles, but getting my app to work so I could move on.